# LomontFFT vs Matlab precision

Tags: c#, matlab, fft

Hello Im using LomontFFT for fft algorithm in my application. When I compare the shape of the my graph and Matlab graph everything is fine, but when I looked closer and compare values I noticed that they are slightly different. For example value 2155,3 in Matlab is 2151,1 in my application.

Here is my question. Did I messed something up in processing or LomontFFT has lower precision than Matlab fft. If LomontFFT has lower precision could yuo suggest me some other class/library to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that LomontFFT gives even more precision than Matlab. I messed up in processing.